# Get Result in Fragment for SearchView using SearchManager on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, searchview, searchmanager

I have a working searchview in a fragment and decided to add voice to it. I followed the guide and created a separate activity to hold the result. This all works fine with the code

```
private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH == intent.action) {
        intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)?.also { query ->
        // blahh blahh `blahhh`
        }
    }
}
```

I now want to send the result to the fragment which has the searchview on it. What is the standard approach to do this from an action (android.intent.action.SEARCH) started from an intent-filter.

I did try and put the intent-filter on the activity which holds the fragment but it seems to launch a new instance so I cannot use findfragmentByTag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anyone trying to do this, all you have to do is follow the docs

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
super.onNewIntent(intent)
handleIntent(intent)
}

private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH == intent.action) {
    intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)?.also { query ->

        Log.d(TAG, "handleIntent: Query received is $query")
        binding.testSearchView.setQuery(query, false)
        Log.d(TAG, "handleIntent: Complete")
    }
}
```

}

And make sure you add

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

To your manifest for the activity which has the SearchView. This prevents the new instance. Sorry bit slow today.